# Jquery does not apply on R Shiny UI

Tags: r, shiny

I have built a webpage using R shiny. In the web Page I have a Table that Contains URLs which are getting rendered as text. I am trying to convert this text as a URL. I wrote a JQUERY function which works perfectly on a normal HTML page but when I include the function as a script in Shiny it doesn't work. Will appreciate any help in this matter

The function I have written is as follows

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('td').each(function(){

        var str = $(this).html();

        var regex = /(https?:\/\/([-\w\.]+)+(:\d+)?(\/([\w\/_\.]*(\?\S+)?)?)?)/ig ;

        var replaced_text = str.replace(regex, "<a href='$1' target='_blank'>$1</a>");

        $(this).html(replaced_text);
    });
});
```

Comment: How are you inserting the script? An edit with the relevant parts of `ui.R` would be helpful.